# How can I remotely test if a machine is hibernated/asleep?

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate, suspend

I'd like to be able to test if a remote Windows machine is asleep or not.  Whether this is suspend or hibernate doesn't matter. I was originally trying to do this with a ping, but I would think that obviously doesn't work since -> WOL.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but I don't think this is possible without some out of band management (ESPECIALLY for hibernation since the system should actually be completely off)

Comment: If Ping is not blocked what is the problem with it? Standard Ping won't wake a computer up if it is hibernating.

Comment: My understanding is that because ping isn't blocked when a computer is in hibernation I would not be able to test what state is in based on if ping is blocked or not.

Comment: Replying to pings is a function of the operating system, so if the computer is sleeping you will **not** get a reply. Conversely if you get a reply then the computer is awake. But if you don't get a reply then it could be that the computer is sleeping but it could also be because the computer is configured **never** to reply to pings.

Comment: Okay, I'm off to do more testing for now then.  Thank you, I'll be back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ping is not working, there are several other command line utilities that can help you test connection to a machine. If you are sure that the machine is connected to your network, then a fail command could only mean that the machine went into hibernation (or it got disconnected from the network). Here are some such utilities:

[1] tracert - The trace route command calculates the number of hops to a destination. You can use it in a similar manner to a ping.

[2] nbtstat - This is a powerful utility in Windows that help you resolve dns names. Typing "nbtstat -a" will list all computers on your network and you can check whether your particular PC is on the list or not.

[3] telnet - If you know that your PC is listening on a particular port (such as 80 for HTTP ,21 for FTP or 20 for SMTP), you can test it with telnet.